# ATtiny13A - PWM x 3, ADC x 2

Tags: arduino, adc, pwm, potentiometer, attiny

I want to control 1 RGB LED and 2 potentiometers by ATtiny13A.
I want control the RGB LED by 3 PWM ports and read values of 2 potentiometers by 2 ADC ports.

1. Is it available by ATtiny13A?
2. Can I program it by Arduino?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ATTINY13A with only 512 program words is a bit small for arduino
and it has only 2 PWM outputs (so you'll be doing the third in software)

if you want a challenge it's probably possible to accomplish your task.

Comment: You mean, if i control other one pin as high or low for pwm then it can be possible?

Comment: yes, possible, but perhaps difficult.  you need to keep your ADC reading loop from messing with your PWM loop too much.